# Checkmarx second order SQL Injection php

Tags: php, prepared-statement, sql-injection, checkmarx

I have a custom function which creates prepared statement. Since I am using prepared statement the checkmarx should not highlight second order SQL Injection issues in this function.

```php
function insertUsingPreparedStmt($table,  $params, $bind_condition)
{

    $dbobj = $this->getMysqliObject();

    $fields             = array_keys($params);
    $values             = array_values($params);
    $question_mark      = '';

    foreach ($values as $id)  $question_mark .= '?, ';
    $question_mark      = rtrim($question_mark, ', ');

    $bind_params[] = &$bind_condition['bind_type'];
    $n = count($values);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $bind_params[] = &$values[$i];
    }


    $query = "INSERT INTO $table (" . implode(" , ", $fields) . ") VALUES ( $question_mark )";

    $stmt = $dbobj->prepare($query);
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $bind_params);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Checkmarx says

> Method `executeStoreProcedure` at **line 994** of `app/Mysqlim.php` gets database data from the `fetch_object` element. This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated, and is eventually used in a database query in method `insertUsingPreparedStmt` at **line 1568** of `app/Mysqlim.php`. This may enable an *Second-Order SQL Injection* attack.

There are like 12 issues of this kind and I am sure these are false positive. How can I get rid of these from checkmarx?

Comment: It's most likely complaining about `$fields             = array_keys($params)` as I assume these values are not checked against a whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

Both the `$table` and the `keys($params)` are possible vectors of SQL injection, because they are interpolated into the SQL query without being validated.

Based on the error, I guess one or both come originally from the database, thus making it a second-order SQL injection. If someone can poison your database by inserting a string, and then that string is queried and is eventually used as the table name or column names, then it's SQL injection.

You often hear people say "use a prepared statement!" as if that's the crucial part. In fact, simply using `prepare()` does not magically make queries safe if they are compromised by SQL injection. It's the *parameters* that make queries safe. But you can use parameters only in place of scalar values in an SQL query, not table identifiers or column identifiers. So how to solve this?

A good solution is to use an *allowlist* to validate the identifiers. A value  you interpolate is safe if it's a fixed value in your code alone, and not an unsafe source such as user input or from an external source like a database, a file, or a web request. The external input can *choose* which value to use, but the value itself is not the external input.

Suppose you had a global variable in your PHP app named `$allMyTables`. Let's say it's a hash where table names are the keys, and this key points to another hash where the column names for that table are keys. Here's an example for a single table:

```
$allMyTables = [
  'mytable' => [
    'id' => true,
    'name' => true,
    'score' => true,
    'created_at' => true,
    'updated_at' => true
  ]
];
```

How you populate this is not important right now. Assume you simply add it as a static PHP file in your project. If you add a table or columns, you would need to edit this PHP file. The point is the values are fixed in your code, they don't come from an external source.

Here's how I'd write your function:

```
function insertUsingPreparedStmt($table,  $params)
{
    global $allMyTables;

    /* first validate that the table exists */
    if (!array_key_exists($table, $allMyTables)) {
        throw new ErrorException("Table $table is unknown. Contact site administrator.");
    }

    /* get the subset of $params for columns known to belong to that table */
    $params = array_intersect_key($params, $allMyTables[$table]);

    $dbobj = $this->getMysqliObject();

    $columns            = array_keys($params);
    $columns_string     = implode(',', array_map(func($col) { return "`$col`"; }, $columns));
    $values             = array_values($params);
    $placeholders       = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($columns), '?'));

    $query = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($columns_string) VALUES ($placeholders)";

    $stmt = $dbobj->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($columns)), ...$values);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

In this example I also made sure to put the table name and column names within back-ticks, just in case they conflict with SQL reserved keywords.

In this function, and in most cases in MySQL, you can pass all parameters as string types. MySQL will do type conversion as needed. There are only a few exceptions to this.

PHP's `...` syntax for [passing an array to a variadic function](https://www.php.net/functions.arguments#functions.variable-arg-list) has been available since PHP 5.6 (circa 2014). It's no longer necessary to use `call_user_func_array()` for such cases.

Actually if I wrote this function, I'd make one other change: I'd use PDO instead of mysqli. It makes some tasks simpler. The last lines of the function would be:

```
    $stmt = $dbobj->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($values);
```